# compare day of week and hour to now

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime

I am looking to figure out if current time falls in between two day and hour schedules, to figure out if we need to display some content (go live) or not,

I am using date_i18n() function, because I am in wordpress, and need the date in the configured timezone.

here is what I have so far:

```
// live = Tuesday at 5:00pm thorugh Sunday at 4:59pm
// not live = Sunday at 5:00pm -> Tuesday at 4:59pm

$now = date_i18n('w-G'); // Date format: Week-Day: 0-6 - Hour: 1-23
echo "Now = ".$now."<br/>";

$live_start = date_i18n('w-G', '2-17'); // = date_i18n('w-G', strtotime('2-17'));
echo "Live Start: ".$live_start."<br/>";

$live_end = date_i18n('w-G', '0-16'); //date_i18n('w-G', strtotime('0-16'));
echo "Live End: ".$live_end."<br/>";

echo "<b>".$now.">=".$live_start." && ".$now."<=".$live_end."</b><br/>";

if(($now >= $live_start) && ($now <= $live_end)){
  echo "Live";
}else{
  echo "Not Live";
}
```

This is what I get:

```
Now = 1-13  
Live Start: 1-13  
Live End: 1-13  
1-13>=1-13 && 1-13<=1-13   
Live
```

I am not sure what it is happening, Current time is correct, Monday 13th hour. 
I have tried adding the strtotime() and "" but no change.

any ideas how to fix it, or maybe the entire code is bad and there is a better way? 
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the data type that you're getting from date_i18ndate_i18n('w-G') can be compared like that.  Try breaking it into the individual parts, so that you have values that can be compared.

```
$nowDay = date_i18n('w');
$nowHour = date_i18n('G'); 

$startDay = 2;
$startHour = 17;

$endDay = 0;
$endHour = 16;


switch ($nowDay) {
    case 0:
        if($nowHour >= $endHour){
          echo "Not Live";
        }else{
          echo "Live";
        }
    case 1:
        echo "Not Live";
    case 2:
        if($nowHour >= $startHour){
          echo "Live";
        }else{
          echo "Not Live";
        }
    case 3:
        echo "Live";
    case 4:
        echo "Live";
    case 5:
        echo "Live";
    case 6:
        echo "Live";
}
```

Comment: if I change the $startHour to before current Hour, and $nowDay to 2, Live is still false, any ideas how to fix this with out having to check for every day and hours?

Comment: The logic was wrong.  It's going to be more complicated than that.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome 
Thank you